# Angularjs ngRoute redirect to "not found" page based on ajax data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm using the examples in https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 and https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08 for demo here. We have the routing below:

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

When we go to the link [/phones/abcdefg](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-8/app/#/phones/abcdefg), no json file matches the query and an empty template appears. In this case, we should be redirected to "404 not found" page. In real case, for example, a json like below would be back when we go to link "/phones/:phoneId" with no matched phoneId.

```
{phoneIdMatch: false}
```

What is the traditional way or the best way in ng-route to redirect to a page **based on the ajax data**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good RESTful backend would respond with a 404 response if asking for a phone that does not exist.

To deal with that response, you would simply add an error callback to your $http promise:

```
$http.get('phones/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json').then(function(response) {
  $scope.phone = response.data;
}).catch(function(response) {
    // do what you want here
});
```

If what you want is go to a specific route like '/404', you would use the $location service:

```
.catch(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 404) {
        $location.url('/404');
    }
});
```

Comment: .success() and .error() are deprecated, use .then() and .catch() instead